# Java JSONObject List comparison using stream

Tags: java, json, arraylist

I have two ArrayList with JSONObject in it,  I need to compare both and find  distinct items from it, so far here is my code some reason  output what I receive is incorrect.

public static void main(String args[]){

```
    JSONObject obj1= new JSONObject();
    obj1.put("id", "1DDX");
    obj1.put("crx", "some random string");
    JSONObject obj3= new JSONObject();
    obj3.put("id", "2DDX");
    obj3.put("BMX", "some random data");
    JSONObject obj2= new JSONObject();
    obj2.put("id", "1DDX");
    obj2.put("crx", "some more random string");

    List<JSONObject> list1= new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    list1.add(obj1);
    list1.add(obj3);
    List<JSONObject> list2= new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    list2.add(obj2);
    list2.add(obj2);

    List<JSONObject> listcom=list2.stream().filter(json-> list1.contains(json.get("id"))).collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(listcom);

The output for equal and not equal comparison
[]
The output for 
List<JSONObject> listcom=list2.stream().filter(!json-> list1.contains(json.get("id"))).collect(Collectors.toList());
[{"crx":"some more random string","id":"1DDX"}, {"crx":"some more random string","id":"1DDX"}]

The output what I am looking for is 
{"BMX":"some random data","id":"2DDX"}
```

Comment: so what's the question here?

Comment: I meant to say is that the output is not correct, I am looking for  distinct JSONObject from list2 after comparing both

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to get the distinct JSONObjects from both lists using the java streaming API, you can concatenate the streams from both lists into a single stream, then use the distinct method on it. Try this:

```
JSONObject obj1= new JSONObject();
obj1.put("id", "1DDX");
obj1.put("crx", "some random string");
JSONObject obj3= new JSONObject();
obj3.put("id", "2DDX");
obj3.put("BMX", "some random data");
JSONObject obj2= new JSONObject();
obj2.put("id", "1DDX");
obj2.put("crx", "some more random string");

List<JSONObject> list1= new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
list1.add(obj1);
list1.add(obj3);
List<JSONObject> list2= new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
list2.add(obj2);
list2.add(obj2);


Stream<JSONObject> jsonStream = Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream);

List<JSONObject> listcom= jsonStream.distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(listcom);
```

**Edit:**

If you are trying to retrieve one value from list1 if it corresponds to a value in list2 you have to map to that value. Try this:

```
List<JSONObject> listcom=list2.stream().filter(json-> list1.contains(json.get("id"))).map(json-> list1.get(json.get("id"))).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Dean, for distinct that works, however what I am looking for is,only an items that is not in list2, basically I need to compare only the id part not the content part.   :  such that 
{"BMX":"some random data","id":"2DDX"}

Comment: in that case you have to map to the result in list one:

Comment: First of all when I filter list2 with list1.contain(json.get("id") it returns a empty array[].  Also the second part of map is returning a compiler error Type mismatch: cannot convert from Stream<Object> to <unknown>